# Concatenating files in Amazon S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3

I have 5 different processes running on different virtual machines (VMs) on EC2 creating 5 different files (f1.txt, f2.txt, f3.txt, f4.txt, f5.txt). These VMs are started at roughly the same time but will finish at different times.

## I need to

~ wait for these 5 files to be written out

~ merge them and create a new file e.g.
  f.txt = f1.txt + f2.txt + f3.txt + f4.txt + f5.txt

~ Questions:
  # How can I determine when all 5 files are ready and written out?
  # Can I use s3cat or some similar command line tool to do that? Does s3cat 
    have similar semantics to Unix cat e.g.
    cat s3://mybucket/f1.txt  > s3://mybucket/f.txt
    cat s3://mybucket/f2.txt >> s3://mybucket/f.txt
    cat s3://mybucket/f3.txt >> s3://mybucket/f.txt
    cat s3://mybucket/f4.txt >> s3://mybucket/f.txt
    cat s3://mybucket/f5.txt >> s3://mybucket/f.txt

```
Their examples on GitHub didn’t show this use case.
```

The output file generated (f.txt) is for use by a downstream process.

---

Answer (score 1):

If you know the names of the keys you are using for the 5 files you are uploading, you can just poll for them. If you know python, boto is a great module for interfacing with s3 and would make handling the above a cinch. Also, s3 does guarantee that a file won't appear to other clients until it has been completely uploaded so you don't have to worry about reading partial files.

Boto is also a good way to concatenate the output if you are already using it check for the files.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want to use multipart uploads, instead of uploading a bunch of files and catting them